# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\cos n}{\sqrt n}$ using comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that we can show that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n} {\sqrt n}$$ converges using Dirichlet's test.

However, how come the following shows the divergence of the same series? Where is the error?

Note that $-1 \leq \cos n \leq 1$. Hence, 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{\sqrt n}\geq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}$$

But we know that $\sum \frac{-1} {\sqrt n} $
diverges as it is a $p$-series. Hence $\sum \frac{\cos n} {\sqrt n}$ must also diverge by the comparison test.

Comment: Comparison test does not work for series with changing sign.

Comment: The only way: Abel.

Comment: Is this due to the condition that $0 \leq a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ for all n to satisfy usage of the direction comparison test?

Comment: Note that $0+0+0+\cdots \ge \sum -1/\sqrt n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with applying the comparison test, the terms of these series don't have a fixed sign.

If $0 \le a_n \le b_n$ and $\sum a_n$ is divergent, then so is $\sum b_n$; in your case, not all the criteria are met.